# 'Hooch' - origins of the word

Tags: home-brew

I would like to know the real origins of the word (terminology) 'Hooch'.  I have done some research [here](http://www.culinarylore.com/drinks:origin-of-the-word-hooch-for-liquor) and [here](http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question119446.html).  However is there another point of view?  If I make my own, can I call it 'Hooch'?

Comment: Chattahoochee!!

Comment: English might be a better fit for this but I think it is OK here also.

Comment: Yup, I thought about that - if anyone wants it migrated that is not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooch means "cheap whiskey" and here is the origin of the term:

> **hooch** (n.)
>
> Also hootch, "cheap whiskey," 1897, shortened form of Hoochinoo (1877) "liquor made by Alaskan Indians," from the name of a native tribe in Alaska whose distilled liquor was a favorite with miners during the 1898 Klondike gold rush; the tribe's name is said by OED to be from Tlingit Hutsnuwu, literally "grizzly bear fort."
>
> As the supply of whisky was very limited, and the throats down which it was poured were innumerable, it was found necessary to create some sort of a supply to meet the demand. This concoction was known as "hooch"; and disgusting as it is, it is doubtful if it is much more poisonous than the whisky itself. [M.H.E. Hayne, "The Pioneers of the Klondyke," London, 1897] - [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hooch)

Comment: Hooch was also used to describe the liquid that would separate from a sourdough starter.  This term was used by the sourdough gold miners in Alaska and the Yukon. ( they are called sourdoughs because of the sourdough starter they brought with them and used to survive on. ) They may have only had flour and water at times and thus sustained themselves on that alone, keeping a working sourdough starter they could pour off the hooch and get a little buzz. i would not recommend it. .